# Dango: form rendering empty fields when calling with POST and an instance of the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to add an *edit* option to a template that just retrieves data from a model and displays it. When the *edit* button is clicked, the form that has been previously filled and saved, should show up being populated with saved data. But in my case, the form is **rendering with empty fields** and showing "This field is required" above each field. How do i render the form in editable mode with fields pre-populated?

This is the view for first time data saving:

```
@login_required
def addprofileView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
           new_user_profile = form.save(commit=False)
           new_user_profile.user = request.user
           new_user_profile.save()
           return redirect('add_license')
    else:
         form = UserProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'addprofile.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is the view for editing and which should return pre-populated form:

```
@login_required
def editprofileView(request, pk):
    ac = get_object_or_404(Account, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=ac)
       if form.is_valid():
           ac = form.save(commit=False)
           ac.user = request.user
           ac.save()
           return redirect('view_profile', ac.pk)
    else:
         form=UserProfileForm(instance=ac)
    return render(request, 'addprofile.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def ProfileView(request, pk):
       profile = Account.objects.filter(pk = pk)
       return render(request, 'userprofile.html', {'pr': profile})
```

What am I doing wrong?

The template that redirects to the editprofileView:

```
 {% block content %}
 {% for p in pr %} 
      Name: {{ request.user.username }} 
      Mobile: {{ p.mobile }} 
      city: {{ p.city }} 
      building no: {{ p.building_no }} 
      state: {{ p.state }} 
      ZIP: {{ p.zip }} 
      Country: {{ p.country }} 
      Sex: {{ p.sex }} 
      <form action="{% url 'edit_profile' p.pk %}" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="submit" value="Edit">
       </form>
   {% endblock %}
```

The action URL in this template sends the Account attribute pk to the editprofileView.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue is that you are POSTing to that view in the first place. You shouldn't; a POST is for *submitting* the data. You don't show that button, but it should either be a simple link, or part of a form with `method="GET"`.